# GWT - Currency Formatter Safe Client and Server Side

Tags: java, gwt

I have an entity which encapsulates some display logic in a method. Within this method, one possible outcome from the display logic is that a BigDecimal property can be displayed as a currency, e.g. `$1,234.56 or ($1,234.56)` for negative values. Other results can be non-numeric String values.

I was using `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat.getFormat("$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)")` to get the format that I need for the currency case, which works just fine in my client-side code, but this entity gets passed client and server-side.

**Is there an alternative to google's NumberFormat that I can use to format this currency, which can be accessed safely in the client and server-side code?**

I don't need all the bells and whistles that the Java standard NumberFormat class provides (server side) or that googles version of NumberFormat (client side).

Edit:

Based on my simple formatting requirements I resolved this issue by writing a custom formatter that is safe client and server side.  However, I am leaving this question open in case any alternatives are out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard Java NumberFormat class on the server side:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

And you can get an instance of a currency format instead of specifying a pattern both in the Java and GWT classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I get how to format the value on both the server and client side, just not sure if there is a way to use a formatter that works for each.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion about getting an instance of the currency format, I'm not sure I follow.  I would assume you meant that my display method would take in some sort of Format instance, but there is no common interface across the server and client side options that I know of.

Comment: I don't see any significant advantage in using the same class. Typically, formatters belong to the presentation layer or parsing data import, so as long as you know which format to use, you can use any formatter that does the job. As for the currency, look at one of the NumberFormat.getCurrencyFormat() methods.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I generally agree with what you are saying and I have given consideration to using a presentation layer formatter as you suggest.  The problem is that in this application users can search and export data and I want consistent formatting logic, ideally without duplicate code, used across the client and server side services that complete this action.

Comment: Why don't you create a Interface that hides logic? Where you just "format", whether is a GWT Formatter or a Standard Java formatter, it will depend on it's provider. To ensure consistency, write unit tests.

Comment: Server-side formatter is mostly useful for parsing data from imported files and the like. For search, consider keeping all of your logic on the client side. You get 100 from the datastore - you display it as $100.00. A user enters 100, 100.00, $100 or $100.00 into a search box - you parse it into 100 and start the search. This way you can keep all parsing/formatting logic in one place.